# How to make 10 random images from resources appear on a button?

Tags: vb.net, image, random

I made a simple game in VB, which goes like this:

A random number between 1-10 appears in a textbox. There are 10 buttons underneath the textbox. If, for example, number 2 appears in the textbox, I quickly have to press number 2 button to gain a point before the number ranomizes again in the textbox.

Anyway, for my question now. I changed the textbox to a button and changed all 10 buttons to images of my choice (all in resources). How do I make the main button randomize between the 10 images? Just like how it works with 1-10 but with images.

I used this code for the 1-10 randomizer:

```
    RandomNumb = Int((10 * Rnd() + 1))
    TextBox1.Text = RandomNumb
```

Comment: So, you dont really want a random image to appear (cat, candle, zebra, house...), you want images from a fixed set (of numerals?) to appear in a random *order*, right?  Also, turn on `Option Strict` that last line assigns a number to a text/string property

Comment: Didnt understand what you mean by random order. I want a random picture from my 10 images to appear in a button, just like 1-10. I have 10 buttons with images attached to them, so when an image appears on the main button, i have to press the correct image button of the 10. I Apologize for my bad explanation

Comment: read your title.  it sounds like you want a set of images assigned to buttons randomly (ie in random order).  And if you dont want repeats there is an extra step.

Comment: Oh lol, no didnt mean it that way( I Should type better title next time) Anyway, now you know what i need help with, Do you know how to help me? :o

Comment: [Edit] your post to clarify and add details.  Where are the images? By `assign them to a button`, you mean there is no text just that image?  *Can* there be repeats?

Comment: The images are in resources(10 images). All 10 buttons have different image(example btn1 have duck and btn2 Fish) The only button that doesnt have image is the button that i want to randomize with the images(This button acts just like the text box that randomized 1-10)

Comment: [edit] your post means [edit] your post.  comments are for asking for clarity.  I still dont know if they can repeat

Comment: err, if 3 or 5 of the 10 buttons can all have fish on them, aren't there 3 or 5 right answers?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6a00c11b9108ffed8e3e516a91f412e8   Here is an image so you can better understand, the text is in swedish. The design is still in WIP so its not done. The textbox is still there, i made a test button called 0. i want one of those 10 random images below to appear on that 0 button, lets say if fish appeared, then i have to click fish. Hope i clarified it now

Comment: yes, and **no image repeats**.  you dont really want 5 ducks to show at once do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesnt indicate where the images are, or if they can repeat (which would indicate a Shuffle).  I would use an `ImageList` in this case because the images are easy to reference and already in a handy container.  Just add an ImageList component to the form, then add the images to it.

Form level declarations:

```
' I am using 5...
Private indicies() As Int32 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
Private buttons As Button()
Private rng As New Random()         ' NET randomizer
```

In form load, initialize the buttons array:

```
buttons = {Button1, Button2, Button3}
```

Then for the "start" button that changes the images displayed on the buttons:

```
ShuffleArray(indicies)

For n As Int32 = 0 To 2
    buttons(n).Image = ImageList1.Images(indicies(n))
Next
```

The key is the method to shuffle the array of indicies.  This puts the array in a random order:

```
' classic Fisher-Yates shuffle
Private Sub ShuffleArray(arry() As Integer)
    Dim tmp As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For n As Integer = arry.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        j = rng .Next(0, n + 1)              ' random index to swap

        tmp = arry(j)

        ' swap item(j) and item(n) 
        arry(j) = arry(n)
        arry(n) = tmp
    Next

End Sub
```

You can have more images than buttons.  I have 5 images but only 3 buttons.  This prevents the same images from coming up over and over, just in a different order.

Comment: You can use the Tag property of the button to store the index of the image assigned.  Do the same for the "question" button and all you can to do is compare those values to see if they answered correctly.  To use Images from Resources, just load them into an Array and use that in place of `ImageList1`

Comment: Working on it currently, seems to be working, getting some results. Thank you for your help :). Sorry it took such time to explain lol

Answer (score 0):

Define an array of filenames and than use them with some math

```
 Dim filenames(n) as String ' n = number of images
 ... ' fill array with filenames
 Button.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(arrOfImages(CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * arrOfImages.Length))))
```

If you want to share your game with others, keep in mind to add the images to the resources of your project and access them from there.